# Java Web Project Build Error

Tags: eclipse, java

I am getting the following 2 error messages, when i try to build my Eclipse project. Can someone tell me why this is occurring ?

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    MavenWeb        Unknown Java Problem
>   Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [jdk1.5.0_10]' in project 'MavenWeb'   MavenWeb        Build path  Build Path Problem

In the projects property window under `Java Build Path` --> `Libraries` and under that it says

> JRE System Library [jdk1.5.0_10] (unbound)

What does this suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the JRE that the project is setup for cannot be found on your local machine.  There are different ways to fix this.  One being, if you go to the Libraries tab on the Java Build Path page, select the JRE System Library and hit edit.

Here you can select a Alternate JRE from your list of installed JREs, or select the workspace default.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install a working or different JRE. I would get the latest and install that then repoint the project to that JRE in Project Properties