# Error: Editor does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using *Jcolibri Studio* and everytime I try to rung my *CBR application* it gives me the error

> Error: Does not contain a main type

May currently Main Method(Jcolibri Studio creates this main):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CBRApplication cbrApp = new CBRApplication();
        try {
            cbrApp.configure();
            CBRCaseBase caseBase = cbrApp.preCycle();

            for(CBRCase c: caseBase.getCases())
                System.out.println(c);

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If I try to `Run As > Java Application`
It gives me a list of classes and ask me to pick one, but I have no idea which one. Tried almost everything and I keep getting receiving this error.

[image: Select Main Type]

Not really sure how important it is, but if you go to *Project's Properties*  you can see this little red X (Pretty sure this JRE is installed).

[image]

Comment: Do you know how a Java program starts running?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you expect to run?

Comment: Already pasted. Sorry about this.

Comment: You want to run a Java program you must have a main function.

Comment: @azurefrog No, it's not. Already checked =\

Comment: Change your JRE lib. Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696613/gettting-jre-system-library-unbound-error-in-build-path)

Comment: @TuyenNguyen Still asking me to pick a "main type" =\

Comment: But are you see your class with main method? If not please provide full code of this class